# Newbie here: delayed calculation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, delay, intervals

I am trying to describe my little problem as simple as possible.

```
data.truck.fuelDiff = utils.formatFloat(data.truck.fuel, 10);
data.truck.fuelDiff2 = utils.formatFloat(data.truck.fuel, 10);

data.truck.fuelConsumption = data.truck.fuelDiff - data.truck.fuelDiff2;
```

This is my simple code to calculate the fuel consumption rate by measuring 2 values by one second difference from the same source.

So `fuelDiff2` should be calculated after 1 second from `fuelDiff` value.

I learned that its impossible to do that via `setinvertal` or `settimeout` because the code executes indefinitely after initialized once.

Now I am looking for a solution to get or copy the `fuelDiff2` value from one second before and leave the `fuelDiff` value real time.

Comment: You know you can use `clearInterval` right? `setTimeout` doesn't execute indefinitely, it's a *timeout*.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` will not execute indefinitely. I will instead wait the specified amount of time before executing the function provided to it.

```
data.truck.fuelDiff = utils.formatFloat(data.truck.fuel, 10);
setTimeout(function() {
  data.truck.fuelDiff2 = utils.formatFloat(data.truck.fuel, 10);
  data.truck.fuelConsumption = data.truck.fuelDiff - data.truck.fuelDiff2;
}, 1000);
```